# Missing Business Intelligence templates for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to follow this tutorial in VS 2017:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdR6WV4kh2Y&t=24s

However, I do not have any Business Intelligence templates.  I've been poking around Google, but not finding anything that helps.

Using the VS Installer, I've already installed Data Storage and Processing, which is the only SQL related option.

I also downloaded Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix, but I can't get it to install. When I try, it tells me:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

Comment: Try installing SSDT. Note that SSDT for VS 2017 has been missing a lot of features and is still in development. Then consider going to an older version of VS until VS 2017 is a solid product. :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt (read the comments if you're unsure about my claim of instability)

Comment: :-) Understood. I have 2015 installed, I'll try that first.